# How to use DisplayMemberPath in WPF CellTemplate?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

In a DataGrid one of the columns is Account. I want to select AccountId but the ComboBox should display AccountNames. So I created the xaml below. It works as required but it has a drawback. If I change the account and go to another cell in the same row then AccountName is not updated yet. (If I leave the row then AccountName is calculated and updated based on the new AccountId.)

If I use only CellTemplate with the ComboBox then I evaded the problem but I do not like this solution because it is not nice to show the ComboBoxes when they are not needed. I could try to update AccountName when I leave the cell but my db view would do that and at this point there could be errors in the current row. So I would like to show the selected AccountName as a TextBlock in CellTemplate based on the AccountId. (I tried to put the ComboBox into the TextBlock but then the TextBlock does not just show the selected AccountName but the ComboBox itself.)

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="{x:Static r:Resource.AccountName}">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding AccountName, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                       Style="{StaticResource TextBlockError}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.AccountObjects}" 
                      SelectedValue="{Binding AccountId, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" 
                      SelectedValuePath="Id"
                      DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                      Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxError}" IsEditable="True"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The answer of @mm8 helped me a lot.
- Until now there was only int AccountId in my model file.
- I introduced Account Account navigation property which created foreign key in the db.

  - (I am using Enitity Framework.)
- When the db is updated Account is not changed only AccountId.

  - (Otherwise there are problems with the db, EF think it should insert a new Account instead using the existing one.)
- Now the setter of the Account property also changes the AccountId.
- Account implements IEquatable

  - otherwise the initial value of the ComboBox is not displayed
- Finally the xaml (SelectedItem="{Binding Account}" and Text="{Binding Account.Name}" is used)

  ```
          <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="{x:Static r:Resource.AccountName}">
              <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Account.Name, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                 Style="{StaticResource TextBlockError}"/>
                  </DataTemplate>
              </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                      <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                          AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.AccountObjects}" 
                                SelectedItem="{Binding Account, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" 
                                                                      DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                                Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxError}" IsEditable="True"/>
                  </DataTemplate>
              </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
              <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
                  <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                      <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                          <Setter.Value>
                              <TextBlock Text ="{Binding Account.Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxWidth="300"/>
                          </Setter.Value>
                      </Setter>
                  </Style>
              </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn>
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You should bind to a `Account` property of your data object and implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netcore-3.1) interface. You may also want to set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` property to `PropertyChanged`:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
            AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.AccountObjects}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding Account, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxError}" IsEditable="True"/>
```

Comment: My DataGrid is bound to a db table where I have the AccountId. That is why I used SelectedValue and AccountId. I can rephrase my question. Is there a way to bind the selected DisplayMemberPath (account name, e.g. HSBC bank) in another column (DataGridTextColumn) in the same row.

Comment: @IstvanHeckl: Not unless there is a name property that gets updated when you select another id to bind to. Setting the `AccountId` property of your "db table" doesn't change the `AccountName` property that your `TextBlock` binds to. That's why you should bind them both to the same property and update this one.

Comment: Thanks a lot to @mm8. Based on your help I could find the solution.